# Hot to Find and close all $MdDialog s?

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I have a timer in my app. If the time is up it's transfer user to login page. 
How to detect if the MdDialog is open and close it?
I don't want to use `angular.element(document).find('md-dialod').remove()` - because some elements like `md-backdrop` or smth else stil exists.
Is there any solutions for this situations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using multiple dialog opening customization? This should work:

```
$timeout(function(){
   $mdDialog.cancel();
}, 8000);
```

Here `$mdDialog.cancel()` hides an existing dialog and reject the promise returned from `$mdDialog.show()`. And even if it's not open calling it will not cause any error.

https://plnkr.co/edit/9nTJNvpO6qU1Bnq1mVML?p=preview

Comment: thanks for your reply. I need to clode dialog from other place, not in the same controller, but something like centrally. For example some service will be responsible for this and after some time detect if one of the possible dialogs is open find it and close it :)

Comment: You can make use of events for that. braodcast using $broadcast/ $emit some custom event from Central parent controller & handle it inside all the controllers where mddialog is used. & On that event in child controllers call $mdDialog.cancel()

Answer (score 1):

(for anyone still using Angular.js in 2022 )

```
const count = $document.find("md-dialog").length;

for (let i = 0; i < count; ++i) $mdDialog.cancel();
```

Park this code anywhere you'd like to trigger your event. I thought you'd need a reference to the existing obj returned by called $mdDialog.show() but apparently not.